# WPF Datagrid with TrulyObservableCollection loses focus on edit

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, wpfdatagrid

Hi I have a WPF datagrid which is bound with `TrulyObservableCollection`, Whenever I try editing a cell through textinput the datagrid cell looses focus after each key entered,

```
public sealed class TrulyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TrulyObservableCollection()
    {
        CollectionChanged += FullObservableCollectionCollectionChanged;
    }

    public TrulyObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> pItems)
        : this()
    {
        foreach (var item in pItems) {
            this.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void FullObservableCollectionCollectionChanged(object sender,
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null) {
            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems) {
                ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null) {
            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems) {
                ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            var a = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
            OnCollectionChanged(a);
        }
        catch {
            // ignored
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my ViewModel, Which is binded to Datagrid,

```
public TrulyObservableCollection<SubLotModel> SubLotCollection
{
    get { return _subLotCollection; }
    set
    {
        _subLotCollection = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SubLotCollection);
        SerialNumberAdded = _subLotCollection.Count;
    }
}
```

In the Datagrid i have a textbox column which is binded to Quantity property in SublotCollection,

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Quantity">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Quantity, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

As soon as i type a valid key in texbox column the cell loses focus.

Comment: My guess would be that each time you type in a letter the view-model `Quantity` property is updated raising the `PropertyChanged` event, which causes your `TrulyObservableCollection` to raise `CollectionChanged` with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`, which in turn causes the `DataGrid` to rebuild itself, causing previously focused editor to lose the focus (possibly it's not even the same editor anymore, but a newly created instance in it's place).

Comment: @Grx70: Good point. But why are you (the OP) raising a Reset event each time a property of an item is changed, i.e. what is the purpose of using the TrulyObservableCollection class?

Comment: I am using TrulyObservable collection so that i can receive notification when an item inside the collection changes as well.

Comment: But why are you raising the Reset event each time an item is changed...? It just doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Diagnosis

As I mentioned in my comment the reason why your editor loses focus is this chain of events:

- You type in a letter, the new text is pushed to the view-model because of the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`
- The `Quantity` property on your view-model is updated and `PropertyChanged` event is raised
- Your `TrulyObservableCollection` handles the `PropertyChanged` event and in consequence raises `CollectionChanged` event with action set to `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`
- The `DataGrid` is designed to rebuild itself on such occasion, so each cell is constructed from scratch (re-templated), and ultimately there's a completely new `TextBox` where there used to be the one you used to type in the letter

The focus is not returned to the new `TextBox` because the `DataGrid` is not really aware of it's existence (since it's defined in a `DataTemplate`). I don't think the focus would be restored even if you used `DataGridTextColumn` either (but you can check).

So the core issue here is the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`. It seems like total overkill to claim the collection was drastically changed when merely one property of one item was changed.

## Solution

Much more reasonable choice would be to raise the `CollectionChanged` with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace` including information which item was "replaced". Together with some improvements here's a collection implementation that should behave like you expect (it did when I tested it):

```
public class TrulyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> 
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged inpc in e.NewItems)
                    inpc.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged inpc in e.OldItems)
                    inpc.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var index = IndexOf((T)sender);
        var args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
            action: NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, 
            newItem: sender, 
            oldItem: sender, 
            index: index);
        //no need to call the override since we've already
        //subscribed to that item's PropertyChanged event
        base.OnCollectionChanged(args); 
    }
}
```